# update an object in a nested array by object id in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am using gridFS to store pdfs and the process by which those pdfs are stored is by assigning a space for them to go and then later uploading into that space. I have all of the necessary pieces of the api in place i believe but something isnt working in my attempt to update the document nested into the resoStatus Object at the Representation Array. here is the code I have written that i think is the closest to correct

```
router.put(
  "/:id/resoStatus/representation/:id",
  upload,
  auth,
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);

    const options = {
      new: true,
      arrayFilters: [{ "elem": req.params.id }],
    };

    const prospect = await Prospect.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.prospectId, {
      "$set": {
        "resoStatus.representation.$[elem].document": req.file.name,
        "resoStatus.representation.$[elem].updatedDate": req.file.uploadDate,
        "resoStatus.representation.$[elem].id": req.body.id,
      },

      options,
    });
    res.json(prospect);
  }
);
```

So basically the upload middleware reads req.file and i want to append that to the object that should be at req.params.id.

Comment: What isn't working? Is there an error message being generated?

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: No array filter found for identifier 'elem' in path 'resoStatus.representation.$[elem].document'